# Are there any differences between "ascribe" and "attribute" when used as "because of"?

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs

Are there any differences between "ascribe" and "attribute" when used as "because of"?

The following two sentences, which one sounds more natural?

> The fall in the number of deaths from heart disease is generally
>   attributed to improvements in diet.
>
> The fall in the number of deaths from heart disease is generally
>   ascribed to improvements in diet.

Thanks.

Comment: I wuold think not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether they mean the same or not is easily ascertained:

> [ODO]
>
> **[ascribe](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ascribe?q=ascribe)** *verb* [*with object*] (**ascribe something to**)
>   regard something as being due to (a cause):
>   *he ascribed Jane’s short temper to her upset stomach*
>
> **[attribute](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attribute?q=attribute)** *verb* [*with object*] (**attribute something to**)
>   regard something as being caused by:
>   *he attributed the firm’s success to the efforts of the managing director*
>   *his resignation was attributed to stress*

Which "sounds more natural" is a subjective question, but [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ascribed+to%2C+attributed+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) can provide some objective data. In your sentences ***I*** would use *attributed to*, which happens to match Google's data, but others may disagree.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So you are saying they are pretty much the same...

Answer (score 1):

My subjective view is that ascribe has a negative connotation, where as attribute has a positive one.

he ascribed Jane’s short temper to her upset stomach. Short temper here, a negative trait.
he attributed the firm’s success to the efforts of the managing director. Success, sth positive.